# Game Center submit score confusion

Tags: ios, xcode, game-center

I have just released a game with a Game Center scoreboard and it's starting to fill up nicely.
There's just 1 thing i'm not sure about. The Today, This Week, All Time sections.

I only submit scores to Game Center when the player sets a new personal high score, not after every game.
Is this the correct thing to do?

I set a high score yesterday and am top of the All Time board, however i'm not on the Today Board and obviously wont be unless I beat my All Time score as none of my scores today are being submitted (unless I beat my all time highest).

Comment: Is this a theoretical question or do you have a problem with your code?

Comment: Well it is code related as I don't know whether I should have my GC submit code run after every game, or just when a high score is achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it everytime if the score is greater than 0, obviously if you don't let your code to send your points unless they are greater than your all time record, you won't aapear on the daily-weekly with the points below your record.

Send it everytime and gamecenter will manage them for you